# Loading new pins on MKMapView as user scrolls and zooms using AFNeworking

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate, mapkitannotation, mkmaprect

Initially I load 10 pins using AFNetworking and plot them on the map and set the map zoom level to fit these 10 pins, however in my database I have 1000 pins and I want to load them as the user scrolls or zooms, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I develop [similar app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/venue-map-for-foursquare-shi/id406174482?mt=8). In my case, I load new pins in `regionDidChangeAnimated` method.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    // load new pins 
}
```

As you know, this method is called by the user scrolls or zooms.